# Capturing android network traffic by setting up a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, android, openvpn

I'm trying to capture an app's network traffic, the proxy option in the Android OS is not proxying everything the app is sending/receiving. Would it be possible to setup a VPN server and analyze all network traffic that is passing though my Android phone?

Comment: VPN running within your own network that would indeed work

Comment: how would I go about setting it up? Would I be using openvpn with wireshark?

Comment: OpenVPN + wireshark (or just plain old tcpdump) will work.  You may need to analyse the data on the external Interface - ie the traffic leaving your network, as, in my experience, OpenVPN tun interfaces and libpcap (the underlying capture mechanism on a Linux system) don't always work.

Comment: @Arya Both/all of the above

Answer (score 0):

http://mitmproxy.org/index.html

This is all you need. It is proxy attacking your application via man-in-the-middle attack and you can see everything application is sending/receiving. Bonus points it works when app is using HTTPS too. (By installing certificates on your device. It's super simple too :) ).

Comment: I would need to run it on Linux am I right?

Comment: It seems it doesn't work anymore on Android 6